# Google sign-in for server-side

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I followed the [tutorial by google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) but I'm having a problem. The callback function is never called.
The code is ran in localhost
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function start() {
            gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: '<my-client-id>',
                    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
                });
            });
        }
        function signInCallback(authResult) {
            document.write("here");
            if (authResult['code']) {
                document.write("code is good");
            } else {
                document.write("error");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $('#signinButton').click(function() {
        auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's as mentioned in the tutorial, but I don't get the `document.write` I put in the callback function.
Also, is there a way a can have the user's username after the sign in was successful?

Comment: Try logging the result instead, `console.log(authResult);`, and check the output in the Developer Tools (press F12). Is there a response?

Comment: Tried it, nothing. It's like it never gets to that function at all

Comment: Hmm, frustrating. Are you sure you assigned `http://localhost:8080` to the `JavaScript origins` in the Developers Console, and removed the Redirect URL? https://console.developers.google.com/

Comment: I assigned `http://localhost` to the `JavaScript origins` and yes, I removed the redirect URL

Comment: Well, that was the problem! I was missing the port! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve the user's username from there?

Comment: Ok, I just followed this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. Make sure you assigned `http://localhost:8080` to the `JavaScript Origins` in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), and that you removed the `Redirect URL`.

Once you get that working, all you need to do to get the userProfile is the following request:

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
   'userId': 'me'
 });
 request.execute(function(resp) {
   console.log('Retrieved profile for:' + resp.displayName);
 });
```